# How to replace string with incremental value in shell script using awk

Tags: unix, search, awk, replace, auto-increment

In unix i am doing a grep ticketnumber filename

I get "ticketnumber": 123

I replace 123 with 124 - using sed -i 's/123/124/g'  filename

How can I do this in awk in a shell script

Comment: All the answers are given as per your shown samples but later you claimed that your requirement is different, I would suggest you to edit your post with proper samples and details so that we could try to help you.

Comment: Can you post a REAL version of an input file? From the segment you've included, it looks like it might be JSON. Create a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that people creating answers can test their results before posting? It's highly discouraging to get back a "no, that's not *really* what I wanted".

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using awk's gsub command:

```
awk '{gsub(/pattern/,"replacement")}' file
```

Referring to your example, changing 123 to 124:

```
awk '{gsub(/123/,"124");}' file
```

Further infos [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/awk-find-and-replace-fields-values/)

I hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$ awk '/ticketnumber/{$2+=1;print}' file
"ticketnumber": 124
```

Comment: I have 1000's of json files for which i need to increment the ticket number. The format of the string is "ticketNumber": 1234 I need to change it to "ticketNumber": 1235

Comment: Well, suit your question to match that requirement and post appropriate sample data with expected output.